Loading View animation don't work as needed in SwiftUI
I created this animation depending on a Boolean value to show as a loading animation. I wanted it to blink only in the middle of the view but it enters the view from top left hand corner, comes into the middle and turns back to top left corner. How to make it act only in the middle?
var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigationPathManager.path) {
            VStack {
                if isLoading {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "pawprint.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                        Spacer()
                        Image(systemName: "pawprint.fill")
                            .resizable()
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    }
                        .opacity(animate ? 0.2 : 1.0)
   .animation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: animate)
                        .onAppear {
                            self.animate = true
                        }

I tried to turn Vstack into Zstack but it didn't work as well.

remove NavigationStack it will work <3

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Why navigationStack causes that then?  And also i have navigation views under this navigationStack. If i remove it I'm not sure if they'll work

your solution actually worked but, later i ll check if my navigationDestination cases will work which was inside navigationStack
